# I have a lot of objects in an ArrayList and at a specific time some of these objects become invalid. How do I discard objects based on time?

Tags: java, multithreading, arraylist

I currently have an ArrayList. At some point, let's say 30 seconds, specific objects become invalid. How do I time it to make specific objects invalid and then remove themself from the ArrayList.

In my object I store the LocalTime at which they were initialized

Currently I have a new thread that is sheduled to run every 15 seconds. It will iterate through the array to check for objects that have met their time. If they have then they are discarded and removed from the list.

Is there are more efficient way of doing this?

Thanks.

Comment: If you don't want to implement this yourself, you could have a look at [Guava Cache with time-based eviction](https://www.baeldung.com/guava-cache#3-eviction-by-time). It behaves more like a `Map` than a `List` though, but might still suit your needs.

Comment: @sp00m Caffeine is the replacement for Guava Cache.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- Oh, you're right! Why am I learning this today only, got quite a few codebases to update now... Thanks for the heads-up :)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of an array, you could use a Map (TreeMap - sorted keys). Timestamp as your key and object as value. Now you have the keys sorted to the timestamp of your object. Your new schedule thread could remove the sorted key-value pairs as per your condition. More performant than using Arrays. Hope this helped !

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).